# gradle-appengine-plugin still using appengine-web.xml?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, app-engine-flexible

I'm trying GAE Java Flexible Environment and using "com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:gradle-appengine-plugin" in my build script.

When I start task appengineRun, it complaints appengine-web.xml is missing. My understanding is for Flexible Environment, the appengine-web.xml is obsolete and replaced by app.ymal file. But I still have this error even if I have app.yaml under src/main/appengine/

My question is, is this a bug in the gradle script? Thanks!

Comment: Try to put app.ymal file in root folder of your app, it should fix it.

Comment: @Yevgen Thank you. It no longer complaints about missing appengine-web.xml then because the runtime generated it from yaml once I moved the file to root folder as you advised. Why don't you put your comment in an answer instead. Besides, I have more questions: my app is a Spring-Boot jar application. Once deployed, all path are forbiden. Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Comment: That's strange, you shouldn't need to appengineRun a springboot app... If anything, springboot apps launch themselves.  Second, if you're going to be doing flexible environment applications, I would recommend trying : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because gradle doesn't know where your app.yaml file is. Move it to root folder of your application.

About spring boot application: it didn't start on app engine because spring boot application requires more time to start then app engine gives by default. So on each your request app engine tries to start your app and after timeout fails.

Comment: Thanks Yevgen, but how do you deduct the conclusion from forbidden to the possible reason that app timeout? Isn't it 404 to be returned rather than 403?